# Append header and footer if they don't exist with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, header, root

How can I have XSLT wrap input XML within a parent node, only if it doesn't already exist?

For example, if my input is:

```
<Project>...</Project>
```

I want to wrap it with a prefix and a suffix:

```
<?xml version "1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<Site>
  <Project>...</Project>
</Site>
```

If however, <Project> is not the root node of the input, I'd like the input to be left unmodified.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a complete and simple solution.

Comment: XSLT may not be the best solution for this particular problem; XSLT essentially generates a whole new XML document based on an existing one and a stylesheet, but in this case it may be preferable to simply manipulate the existing document; I know in C# it would be fairly easy to remove the node from it's current child, put a `<Site>` tag in it's place, and re-add it as a child of the new element.

Comment: I understand the comments about it being easier through other means. The app already deploys with various transforms to upgrade old or dodgy inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/Project">
        <Site>
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </Site>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input 1:

```
<Project>...</Project>
```

Output 1:

```
<Site>
    <Project>...</Project>
</Site>
```

Input 2:

```
<Root>
    <Project>...</Project>
</Root>
```

Output 2:

```
<Root>
    <Project>...</Project>
</Root>
```

**Note**: Identity transformation. Pattern matching

Comment: @DJC: Your are wellcome! Ask any time.

Answer (score 1):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[not(self::site)]/Project">
  <site>
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  </site>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

wraps the element `<Project>` only when it is not already a child of a `<site>` element.

**When applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
  <Project>x</Project>
    <site>
      <Project>y</Project>
    </site>
</t>
```

**the correct, wanted result is produced**:

```
<t>
   <site>
      <Project>x</Project>
   </site>
   <site>
      <Project>y</Project>
   </site>
</t>
```

Comment: From the question: "<Project> is not the root node of the input, I'd like the input to be left unmodified"

Comment: A useful answer for my toolbox, particularly the not match, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If adding only the prefix and suffix is your requirement then you can look for other Unix options like grep which can do this much simpler.
If you want to do this in XSL then you shuld use xsl:when

```
<xsl:template match="/">
         <xsl:choose>       <!-- If Node Period exists add the text -->         <xsl:when test="Period">
                        <xsl:text><Site></xsl:text>
                        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:text><Site></xsl:text>
            </xsl:when>     </xsl:choose>   <xsl:apply-templates select="Notification"/> </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I had difficulty getting it to work, I'm sorry.